# Creating a Lambda event handler with the AWS Go SDK v2

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to write an event handler in Go using the AWS SDK v2, but I'm getting nil pointer dereference errors as you can see in the following code block:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference",
  "errorType": "errorString",
  "stackTrace": [
    {
      "path": "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/errors.go",
      "line": 39,
      "label": "lambdaPanicResponse"
    },
    {
      "path": "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/function.go",
      "line": 36,
      "label": "(*Function).Invoke.func1"
    },
    {
      "path": "runtime/panic.go",
      "line": 969,
      "label": "gopanic"
    },
    {
      "path": "runtime/panic.go",
      "line": 212,
      "label": "panicmem"
    },
    {
      "path": "runtime/signal_unix.go",
      "line": 742,
      "label": "sigpanic"
    },
    {
      "path": "eventHandler/main.go",
      "line": 252,
      "label": "getTargetGroup"
    },
    {
      "path": "eventHandler/main.go",
      "line": 187,
      "label": "HandleRequest"
    },
    {
      "path": "reflect/value.go",
      "line": 476,
      "label": "Value.call"
    },
    {
      "path": "reflect/value.go",
      "line": 337,
      "label": "Value.Call"
    },
    {
      "path": "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/handler.go",
      "line": 124,
      "label": "NewHandler.func1"
    },
    {
      "path": "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/handler.go",
      "line": 24,
      "label": "lambdaHandler.Invoke"
    },
    {
      "path": "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go@v1.22.0/lambda/function.go",
      "line": 64,
      "label": "(*Function).Invoke"
    },
    {
      "path": "reflect/value.go",
      "line": 476,
      "label": "Value.call"
    },
    {
      "path": "reflect/value.go",
      "line": 337,
      "label": "Value.Call"
    },
    {
      "path": "net/rpc/server.go",
      "line": 377,
      "label": "(*service).call"
    },
    {
      "path": "runtime/asm_amd64.s",
      "line": 1374,
      "label": "goexit"
    }
  ]
}
```

My import statement is as follows. As you can see, I am importing the lambda-go runtime:

```
import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/config"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ec2"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/ecs"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/elasticloadbalancingv2"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/elasticloadbalancingv2/types"
    "log"
    "strings"
    "time"
)
```

My code looks like this:

```
func main() {
    lambda.Start(HandleRequest)
}
func HandleRequest(e ECSEvent) error {...}
```

ECSEvent in the handler's signature is a struct that matches the incoming EventBridge event. Is there some trick to getting the Go SDK v2 to work with Lambda?

Answer (score -1):

The lambda function didn't have permission to make an AWS API call.